# How to keep track of indices using map and lambda expression?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, indices

While I am executing the code below, I would like to keep track of the indices because I need to sort the result list afterwards:

```
my_list = np.array([[[5,8], [2,2], [9,5]], [[5,8], [9,5], [2,2]], [[9,5], [5,8], [2,2]]])

result = list(map(lambda x: myFunction(list(map(lambda x: x[0:], x))), my_list))
```

I've tried to use `enumerate(my_list)` but I got the error:

```
result = list(map(lambda x: myFunction(list(map(lambda x: x[0:], x))), enumerate(my_list)))
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

If I use for loop with enumerate, it works fine, but I would like to know if there is another solution using `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate generates a sequence of value pairs, so your lambda function needs to unpack the pairs of values:

Try:

```
result = list(map(lambda x: myFunction(list(map(lambda y: y[0], y[1][0:], y[1]))), enumerate(my_list)))
```

Where:

1. y is the pair (i, x) on each iteration of map from enumerate
2. i is the index
3. x is the ith sublist of my_list.

The lambda function needs to unpack y to get i and x back

> With:  i = y[0] and x = y[1])

Since this now sends triplets to myFunction you also should update it to accept triplets.